# undefined t variable in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a gaussian wave `cos((0.1*x)*exp(-sqrt(x)/2*sqrt(t)))` in gnuplot. I define a range for `t` by:

```
set trange [0.1:2] 
plot cos((0.1*x)*exp(-sqrt(x)/2*sqrt(t)))
```

but it stops with `undefined variable t` error. What should I do?

Comment: Did you define a `t` somewhere before? In the code you have, there is no `t` defined, so I'd agree with the error.  What value for `t` do you expect it to use?

Comment: a range of data between[0.1:2]. Should I define t before giving it a set trange?

Comment: `set trange` is for parametric plots.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes. The main variable is 'x' which I dont want to set a range for it. I have another variable which I want to be in a range and that's 't'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot command works with functions of a single variable.  Thus it will fill in the `x` value, but when it encounters `t`, it doesn't know what to do with that.

If you had previously defined `t`, it would use that value.  Thus

```
t = 0.5
plot cos((0.1*x)*exp(-sqrt(x)/2*sqrt(t)))
```

will work just fine, using a value of 0.5 for t.

If you wish to plot multiple curves for a range of t values, you can use the `plot for` syntax doing something like

```
plot for [t=0:10] cos((0.1*x)*exp(-sqrt(x)/2*sqrt(0.1+t*0.19)))
```

which will plot the curve for a range of values.  As the for syntax works with integers, we need to use an integer value for the loop and then calculate the value for the formula (`0.1+t*0.19` ranges from 0.1 to 2 as required when t ranges from 0 to 10).  You can label the key using

```
plot for [t=0:10] cos((0.1*x)*exp(-sqrt(x)/2*sqrt(0.1+t*0.19))) title sprintf("t=%f",0.1+t*0.19)
```

---

Setting a range will only work with variables that the plot command understands.  As `t` isn't one of them (except in parametric mode), the range command doesn't do anything in this case.